# matlab : remove concatentaion between values

Tags: matlab

I have a function that returns 4 values :

```
[a1 , a2 , a3 , a4] = myFonction(x,y)
```

when calling this function, the values a1,a2,a3,a4 are concatenated as below:

```
truefalsevalue1value2
```

how could I get

```
true false value1 value2
```

---

function :

```
 function [a1, a2, a3, a4] = myFonction(v1,v2)
    a1 = getvalueFromfile(v1,v2,'text');
    a2 = getvalueFromfile(v1,v2,'value');
    a3 = getvalueFromfile(v1,v2,'attribute');
    a4 = getvalueFromfile(v1,v2,'color');
end
```

Comment: Sounds like 1) your function returns strings 2) your `format` settings are messed up 3) other. Could you provide an actual sample of the function output, and/or the abstract, minimal version of the function's code?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If your function is written to return 4 variables that's what it will return.  You'd better show us the code of your function.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, but can't be certain because you haven't posted your code, that at the end of the `.m` file defining your function you have a line like this:

```
[a1,a2,a3,a4]
```

which would cause the values of those variables to be printed out -- note the lack of a trailing ';' to suppress output from intermediate evaluations inside a function definition.  Those values would be printed out without spaces between them rather as you report.

However, that still doesn't mean that the values of the 4 output variables are not returned correctly if you call the function properly, perhaps like this:

```
[one,two,three,four] = fit(v1,v2)
```

But really, how can you expect us to answer your question when you don't post (enough of) your code ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  From your Matlab command window cut the line you use to call your function (*ie* the line beginning with the prompt >>) and the line(s) returned when the command is executed, and paste them into your question.